# cleft sentence + to be verb

Tags: be

**It's in London that he met his wife**  - I've got this sentence in my grammar book under cleft sentences. It's just one of many.

I was wondering if it's possible to use to be verb (I've got no single example). **It's from London that I am.** Would that be correct?

I know it's not how people usually say something like that but I'm asking about cleft sentences and the way they work

Comment: It is not grammatically incorrect, but as you surmise, it is quite an awkward sentence. I would say it's grammatically dubious: there is no real rule that prohibits it, but it is so uncommon and rare that it is likely to be fairly jarring to any native speaker.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet How about **it's my wife I'm worried about?**

Comment: "It's my wife I'm worried about" is fine. "It's from London that I am" is grammatically questionable.

Comment: @PeterShor Oops the wife sentence is a bit different. I meant something like **It's with my wife that I'm angry.** and **It's about  the tv show she's crazy** Are these correct?

Comment: Those are both stilted and not very natural, but not as jarring as “It’s from London that I am”. When there's a predicative after the copula, it works; when the predicative is the bit that's fronted by cleaving the sentence, things start to get shaky.

Comment: Yoda might say *It's from Dagobah that I am*, but most of the rest of us would say it not.

Comment: Ending a clause with _am_ is very jarring. It's virtually always contracted with the pronoun to form ***I'm***, which can't appear finally. And it's never meaningful, so it shouldn't be moved to the focussed final position by clefting, which is for getting **important** constituents at the beginning and end, where they're in focus. And the trouble was caused by pied-piping the _from_ of _be from_ (the idiom referring to place of origin) away from after _am_, where it identifies the idiom, to the beginning of the clause, where it obscures it. Way too much unnecessary syntax here.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I wouldn’t say that ending a clause with _am_ is jarring per se. There are plenty of cases where doing so is not only perfectly natural, but required: “That’s the kind of man I am”, “I have no idea where I am”, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English has two *be*’s, equative and predicative, and both of them seem uniformly to be bad with *it*-clefts.  Compare:

Noun phrase:

> Susan is president / a president / the president.
>
> ?? It’s (a/the) president that Susan is.

Adjective:

> Susan is horsy.
>
> ?? It’s horsy that Susan is.

Prepositional phrase:

> Susan is under the table.
>
> ?? It’s under the table that Susan is.

And for something truly appalling, a *wh*-phrase:

> Susan is who you should ask.
>
> ?? It’s who you should ask that Susan is.

This seems to be a fact about the interaction of *it*-clefts with *be*, rather than just *be* by itself though, as many of these sentences are fine with *wh*-clefts; for instance:

> What Susan is is the president.
>
> What Susan is is horsy.
>
> Where Susan is is under the table.

My guess is some clever linguist specializing in the semantics of *it*-clefts will have to unravel this nice catch of a conundrum.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there's auxiliary _be_ too, but it's leaving that aside that I was.

Answer (score 0):

It is an interesting question. I tried to give a comment on this, but for some reason, I can not post it above.

I think the following expressions could be alternative ways for them.

> It's London where he met his wife.
>   It's London where I am from.

I am not sure that those are cleft sentences (maybe not), but you can put some stress on London more than the plain expressions--he met his wife in London, and I am from London.